# How to Show terminal output in a NSScrollView in Applescript?

Tags: xcode, applescript-objc

I can do this with a textField as follows:

`property textField : missing value
set theOutput to do shell script "blahblahbla" with administrator privileges
tell textField to setStringValue_(theOutput)`

but when trying to do the same with ScrollView I get the following Error: -[NSScrollView setStringValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003d0c3c0
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because the **NSScrollView** class doesn't have a **setStringValue:** method.  If you are talking about using an **NSText*View***, in the Interface Editor, drag in a Text View object - this is embedded in a Scroll View.  Click through (or select) the Scroll View, Clip View, and Text View as desired, making changes in the Attributes Inspector (font, scroll bar settings, etc).  Make your outlet connection to the Text View, and use its **setString:** method to set the string property.

Comment: I want to use NSScrollView, I currently use NSTextView as described above and this works fine.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are wanting to do?  In the Interface Editor, the **Text View** object is a **NSTextField** in a NSClipView in a NSScrollView, while the **Scroll View** object is a **NSView** in a NSClipView in a NSScrollView.  They both move and display the item view in the scroll view, so it is actually the text field or view that you are using.

Comment: I want to use the text field but with the scroll option, using a Text Field / Text Field Cell I can set the output produced by the terminal in it.

Comment: In the Interface Editor, use a **Text View** object - this is embedded in a Scroll View.  I've clarified this (hopefully) in my answer.